# How to set the properties of an Azure Table through python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to enable CORS for a specific azure account/table from the python sdk.

Unfortunately the docs do not cover that topic. From looking [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py) I know that I must use the `set_table_service_properties()` and pass the `storage_service_properties` argument. But I don't know how is this argument supposed to be formatted.

Should I create a dictionary that when passed to the xml converted will produce something like that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StorageServiceProperties>
    <Logging>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <Delete>true</Delete>
        <Read>false</Read>
        <Write>true</Write>
        <RetentionPolicy>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Days>7</Days>
        </RetentionPolicy>
    </Logging>
    <HourMetrics>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <IncludeAPIs>false</IncludeAPIs>
        <RetentionPolicy>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Days>7</Days>
        </RetentionPolicy>
    </HourMetrics>
    <MinuteMetrics>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <IncludeAPIs>true</IncludeAPIs>
        <RetentionPolicy>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <Days>7</Days>
        </RetentionPolicy>
    </MinuteMetrics>
    <Cors>
        <CorsRule>
            <AllowedOrigins> http://www.fabrikam.com,http://www.contoso.com</AllowedOrigins>
            <AllowedMethods>GET,PUT</AllowedMethods>
            <MaxAgeInSeconds>500</MaxAgeInSeconds>
            <ExposedHeaders>x-ms-meta-data*,x-ms-meta-customheader</ExposedHeaders>
            <AllowedHeaders>x-ms-meta-target*,x-ms-meta-customheader</AllowedHeaders>
        </CorsRule>
    </Cors>
</StorageServiceProperties>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is shortly going to be fixed in the [next version](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/issues/57) of the Python library (to be released very soon, see the dev branch), but at the moment the library doesn't support setting CORS.

In the new version, it will be settable something like [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/dev/samples/table/table_usage.py#L458) shows.