# Azure Table Storage Authenticate REST call through javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to make a REST call to my Azure Table using javascript but I find it hard to authenticate the call.

I am using that piece of javascript (I know the date has to be maximum 15 min old, and I don't plan on using the actual key in the javascript!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var dateTimeInUtc = 'Fri, 12 Feb 2016 12:14:00 GMT';
        var version = '2015-04-05';
        var key = 'JEwMjqFD1ng8vIaECmRw8eQysiIvH08nF/jPKPYaNGumgxtKIjltX8bte5sKN6SNyw09s=='; // not an actuall key
        var stringToSign = 'GET\n\n\nFri, 12 Feb 2016 12:14:00 GMT\n/myaccount/mytable(PartitionKey=\'first_partition\', RowKey=\'1235\')';
        var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToSign), CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key)));
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey=\'first_partition\', RowKey=\'1235\')',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('well done');
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "SharedKey " + "myaccount" + ":" + signature);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-date', dateTimeInUtc);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', version);
            },
            error: function (rcvData) {
                console.log(rcvData);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

what I get

```
403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
```

Do you see anything obviously wrong? Do I miss something from the signature?

Comment: I'm curious to know if CORS has been set properly?

Comment: I set it through http://www.cloudportam.com/ eventually, because the python sdk doesn't offer that functionality [yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342136/how-to-set-the-properties-of-an-azure-table-through-python-sdk). For skipping the configuration part for the moment I just added an extra cors rule similar to the default one that cloudportam uses and I added my origin. So all actions are allowed, allowed and exposed headers are set to * and max age 500.

Comment: The error response may include a body which will tell you the string-to-sign that the service is expecting. You can use this to debug your string-to-sign. Also, take a look at the .NET library's implementation:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Core/Auth/SharedKeyTableCanonicalizer.cs#L72

Comment: Also, make sure your string-to-sign is based on the resource path after percent encoding. For example, the space after the comma will probably be encoded over the wire. You can use a tool such as fiddler to check the exact URL you are transmitting and ensure that your signing is consistent.

Comment: @MichaelRoberson-MSFT Solved! The problem was the space after the comma. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string-to-sign that you construct must be the exact URL transmitted over the wire, including percent encoding characters not allowed in a URL. In this case, the space character in the URL will be percent encoded over the wire, so it must be percent encoded in the string-to-sign.

From the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx):

> Any portion of the CanonicalizedResource string that is derived from the resource's URI should be encoded exactly as it is in the URI.

Comment: Actually removing the space from both the url and the string-to-sign made it work

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [`documentation for creating authorization header`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx), to create the string to sign:

> 1. Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/), followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>      accessed.
> 2. **Append the resource's encoded URI path, without any query parameters.**
> 3. Append a new-line character (\n) after the resource name.

However in your code, you're not including `(PartitionKey=\'first_partition\', RowKey=\'1235\')` there which should be included.

Can you try something like the following:

```
var stringToSign = 'GET\n\n\nFri, 12 Feb 2016 12:14:00 GMT\n/htirawdata/htirawdata(PartitionKey=\'first_partition\', RowKey=\'1235\')';
```

Comment: Oops. I forgot to remove the real name from that line!

Comment: What you suggested is probably correct, but I still get the same result :/

Comment: Try putting a new line character towards the end of stringToSign.

Comment: If that was a CORS configuration related issue (eg wrong list of exposed headers) wouldn't it be obvious?

Comment: No idea, the answer was indeed useful!